# Out of memory when using numpy's multivariate_normal random sampliing

Tags: python, memory, numpy

I tried to use numpy.random.multivariate_normal to do random samplings on some 30000+ variables, while it always took all of my memory (32G) and then terminated. Actually, the correlation is spherical and every variable is correlated to about only 2500 other variables. Is there another way to specify the spherical covariance matrix, rather than the full covariance matrix, or any other way to reduce the usage of the memory?

My code is like this:

```
cm = [] #covariance matrix  
for i in range(width*height):  
    cm.append([])  
    for j in range(width*height):  
        cm[i].append(corr_calc()) #corr is inversely proportional to the distance    
mean = [vth]*(width*height)  
cache_vth=numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cm)
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: From this and your other question I am starting to see that what you have is not a spherical covariance matrix. A spherical covariance matrix has all items in the diagonal equal, and all off diagonal elements zero. I am guessing here, but it seems that only about 2500 of 30000 elements in each row of your matrix are non-zero. Is this correct? It may be possible to do what you want using a coordinate change and scipy's sparse module, but more information on the actual structure of your covariance matrix is needed.

Comment: Yes, each row has 2500 non-zero elements. While, it is just a simplification of the problem. The whole problem is like this: there is a 512X512 array of variables, every variable is correlated to its neighbour within the radius of 256, and the correlation coefficient is some kind of inversely proportional to the distance. So I tried to treat this array as an 1-D array with size of 512x512=262144, and build the `cm`(whose size is 262144x262144) for it, then make a multivariate random sample.

Answer (score 1):

If your correlation is spherical, that is the same as saying that the value along each dimension is uncorrelated to the other dimensions, and that the variance along every dimension is the same. You don't need to build the covariance matrix at all, drawing one sample from your 30,000-D multivariate normal is the same as drawing 30,000 samples from a 1-D normal. That is, instead of doing:

```
n = 30000
mu= 0
corr = 1
cm = np.eye(n) * corr
mean = np.ones((n,)) * mu
np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cm)
```

Which fails when trying to build the `cm` array, try the following:

```
n = 30000
mu = 0
corr = 1
>>> np.random.normal(mu, corr, size=n)
array([ 0.88433649, -0.55460098, -0.74259886, ...,  0.66459841,
        0.71225572,  1.04012445])
```

If you want more than one random sample, say 3, try

```
>>> np.random.normal(mu, corr, size=(3, n))
array([[-0.97458499,  0.05072532, -0.0759601 , ..., -0.31849315,
        -2.17552787, -0.36884723],
       [ 1.5116701 ,  2.53383547,  1.99921923, ..., -1.2769304 ,
         0.36912488,  0.3024549 ],
       [-1.12615267,  0.78125589,  0.67133243, ..., -0.45441239,
        -1.21083007,  1.45696714]])
```

Comment: Thank you for help! I think it is true that the problem comes from building the `cm` array. It looks like that your code treat every variable as independent from each other, right? While I the `cm` is not diagonal, since some variables are correlated.